# Can't install azure sdk for linux/python

Tags: python, ubuntu, azure, sdk

After downloading the SDK and discovering it really does extract even though it throws a ton of warning and writes the output to a non-standard location, I then discovered more non-standard stuff - it wants npn adn node installed.  Furthermore it capitalizes their names even though they shouldn't be.

So, I finally installed those and now when I run ./configure for the SDK it tells me it needs node V0.6.15 or higher and as you can see here, I'm running 0.10.0

```
mjs@ubuntu:/tmp/azure$ ./configure 
Node version needs to be higher than 0.6.15
Npm is installed. Version: 1.2.14
mjs@ubuntu:/tmp/azure$ node --version
v0.10.0
```

also, if I read the SDK INSTALL file it says:

### Unix/Macintosh

- Requires Python 2.6 or 2.7
- Requires Node.js 6.15 or greater, as well as npm (http://nodejs.org/#download)

but if I go to the nodejs website it clearly states the latest version is 0.10.0.  Has anyone successfully installed this on ubuntu or am I wasting my time?

Comment: I am looking into it..

Answer (score 0):

node 0.10 is a very recent release, the previous stable release was was 0.8.22.  Currently, the azure sdk for node doesn't support versions above 0.8.x - you can easily install one of the previous stable versions (like 0.8.22)from http://nodejs.org/dist/

Answer (score 0):

I blogged on this here: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/03/18/node-0-10-compat-issues-with-the-azure-sdk-and-cli/

We're definitely working on it.